# Can't edit cell using VBA if the data in cell is more than 255 characters

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I am trying to edit the data in a cell using VBA as follows:

`ActiveCell.Characters(155,1).Text = "Adding Text Here"`

It is working good if the character count less that 255 but not working for more than 255 characters.

My cells have data with some colors for rows as follows. The lines should not lose the color, but I should add some text in middle.

```
Bread Q1 Required
Jam Q2 NotRequired
Water Q1 Required
Drink Q3 Require
Jam Q2 NotRequired
Water Q1 Required
```

I am using Office 2003.

Answer (score 1):

see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)
for official limitations of office 2003. AFAIK there's no workaround, even with newer versions of excel. Of course you could always split up the content of these cells across several cells and then use `&` to concatenate them in VBA.

Comment: I think concatenation makes loose the formatting. The problem remains the same with Excel 2016, that's a pitty!